# Duplicate weighted ties in social network using R

Tags: r, duplicates, sna, weighted-graph, graphical-programming

I am wondering if there is a way for any social network package (sna, network, or igraph) to accommodate duplicate ties with different weights?

I have data where division chiefs are rating their organization as you can see below, and there are some duplicate ties (last two rows) where division (rater) and organization (target) are the same but the ratings/weights are different. This seems to be a problem when trying to assign weights to the ties/edges and calculate network metrics such as degree centralization.

I would greatly appreciate any help you can provide. Thank you!

| ResponseID | Division | Organization | Ratings |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9HqI3t7EGqrKebf | 320 | A | 6.60 |
| 3R1kgxyURf5N8bZ | 630 | A | 5.80 |
| 3EuRMA5lrEGcSuU | 140 | B | 5.20 |
| 1jAL0geqMvU4LQN | 440 | B | 6.60 |
| 2WYBoes8GTl3yGm | 170 | B | 6.40 |
| 3fZQaD89U4n6hr0 | 630 | C | 6.20 |
| 3fH3TnHvHxbbZjo | 630 | C | 6.40 |

To reply to the comment below, I have tried loading attributes using "network" package.

valuedNetDC <- network(DVsubVom[,2:3],loops=TRUE)

Here, the columns 2 = Division, columns 3 = Organization.
I am getting an error message as shown below:

Error: `multiple` is `FALSE`, but `x` contains parallel edges. The following rows in `x` are duplicated: - `x[5, ]` - `x[10, ]` - `x[17, ]` - `x[19, ]` - `x[20, ]` - `x[23, ]`

Comment: What have you tried? Right now this is more of a "I'm looking for a library" question, which is off-topic for SO

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.